# How to pass an object from a Frame to another Frame in a Windows 8 Style App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have problem that i just cant figure out right now.
I am trying to develop a Windows-8 style app and im stuck implementing this functionality.

I have a **MainWindow** which contains a ListBox and a Button (lets say **addButton**).

When i click the button i navigate to a new page, lets say **AddCustomerPage** with this.Frame.Navigate(typeof (AddCustomerPage));

**AddCustomerPage** has 1 textBox and 1 button (lets say **doneButton**. When i click the button i want the string in the textBox to be added to the ListBox on the previous page.

This is my current functionality:
1. MainWindow is created.

1. Click addButton
2. AddCustomer page is created. MainWindow is destroyed(problem).
3. Click doneButton
4. A MainWindow object is created with a ListBox with 1 item.
5. Repeat the add process, i always get a MainWindow with a ListBox with 1 item.

Thanks for the help. Here is the code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.brainPageController = new PageController();

        // add items from the List<String> to the listBox
        listGoals.ItemsSource = brainPageController.GetListGoals();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var parameter = e.Parameter as String;
        // a simple controller that adds a string to a List<string>
        brainPageController.AddGoal(parameter);
    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof (GoalsInfo));
    }

    // VARIABLES DECLARATION
    private PageController brainPageController;
}

public sealed partial class GoalsInfo : WinGoalsWIP.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{
    public GoalsInfo()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.brainPageController = new PageController();
    }

    protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
    }
    protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        brainPageController.AddGoal(nameTextBox.Text);

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), nameTextBox.Text);
    }
    // VARIABLES DECLARATION
    PageController brainPageController;
}
```

Comment: If you paste some of your code it will be a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i hope it helps

[Quickstart: Navigating between pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), nameTextBox.Text);
```

Then in OnNavigatedTo of `MainPage`

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string text = e.Parameter as string;
    if (text != null) {
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

If you want to cache your MainPage then do this

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //This will cache your page and every time you navigate to this 
        //page a new page will not be created.
        this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;

        this.brainPageController = new PageController();

        // add items from the List<String> to the listBox
        listGoals.ItemsSource = brainPageController.GetListGoals();
    }
```