# Passing data between multiple forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am creating a WindowsPhone app and (at the moment) I have three pages. Page1, page2 and page3. Page1 has two (2) textboxes that accepts the fist and last name, txtFN and txtLN and a button. The button takes you to the form2, that asks you the nickname. That has one textbox and a button. When the user clicks the button, it takes him the form3 that has a textblock. The nickname the user inputs in form2, displays in form3, on the textblock. I have gotten that part correct. Now, I am trying to do this: if the user does not input anything in the nick name section, I would like to show the first name in form three. Here's my code for form2->form3 event:

in form2:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page4_phone_Number_extraction), "Alright " + Texbox_nickname_extraction.Text + "!");
}
```

in form3,

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Textblock_nickname_display.Text = e.Parameter.ToString();
}
```

And this works like a charm..

Again, for the life of me, i can't think of how to have the first name show up in form3, if there is no user input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass an object from a Frame to another Frame in a Windows 8 Style App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890836/how-to-pass-an-object-from-a-frame-to-another-frame-in-a-windows-8-style-app)

Comment: I don't think that resolves my issue, but thanks.. Mine does not have a list, so the coding is not that complicated. I am just not getting the logic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to store the data in a local app settings like:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["FirstName"] = txtFN.txt;
```

in page 1.

You can then extract it in page 3 as:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
Textblock_nickname_display.Text=localSettings.Values["FirstName"].ToString();
```

You can also use OnNavigatedFrom() to achieve the same functionality, but it involves more work:

In Page1:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Page2 destinationPage = e.Content as Page2;
    if (destinationPage != null)
    {
        destinationPage.FirstName = txtFN.Text;
    }
}
```

Make sure to have a `string FirstName {get;set;}` in Page2. Now use the same method to send the variable to Page3 too. You can then use the FirstName variable in Page3.

Needless to say, the first method is simpler.

Comment: Edited answer to add alternate method of achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's documentation [contains an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) that shows that you shouldn't use `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` like you did but instead:

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    string name = e.NavigationParameter as string;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        tb1.Text = "Hello, " + name;
    }
    else
    {
        tb1.Text = "Name is required.  Go back and enter a name.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i will give this a try, but I didn't understand why we can't use OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) o.O