# How to use a string in a different cs file

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

I am trying to use `string user = textbox1.Text;` in a welcomePage.cs file like this, `string user = MainPage.textbox1.Text;` I keep getting the error seen    here:

[image]

here is the updated the photo:https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCSMT.jpg

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Gregoua_Technologies
{
public sealed partial class welcomePage : Page
{
    public MainPage mpInstance;

    public welcomePage(MainPage mp)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //Will put the MainPage that this was called from into a variable
        this.mpInstance = mp;
    }

    public void test_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the instance of main page, and get the textbox1 text.
        string user = this.mpInstance.textbox1.Text;
        box.Text = "User: " + user;
    }

    public void priv_Clicked(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(TermsAndConditions), null);
    }

    public void function_Clicked(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FunctionPage), null);
    }
    public void terms_Clicked(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(TermsAndConditions), null);
    }
   }
 }
```

my post is mostly code i guess so here u go staack overflow

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between static variables and instance variables. `textbox1` is an instance variable (Within the MainPage class), so you need to access it using the instance of MainPage that was created (Usually when the application is loaded).

You need to pass information from your previous page (MainPage) to your welcomePage.

Change `welcomePage()` to:

```
public string username;

public welcomePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.username = e.Parameter as string;
}

public void test_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //string username = test.Text;
    box.Text = "User: " + this.username;
 }
```

And be sure to pass your username to welcomePage from your MainPage class:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(welcomePage), this.textbox1.Text);
```

Comment: but don't i need MainPage. first?

Comment: the variable was created in a different cs file

Comment: thank you, but now i get, " welcomePage does not contain a definition for 'mp' etc..

Comment: the app now launches, then crashes when i click the 'next button in the mainPage, which is supposed to take me to welcomePage

Comment: it says 0 errors, but when it crashes, it says,"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Post your updated code, so we can figure out what the issue is.(And specifically what line the null reference exception is coming from.)

Comment: ok i will be sure to do that in just a second; ive added some things unrelated to the topic

Comment: @Greg Your next button?

Comment: public void next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string user = textbox1.Text;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(welcomePage), null);
        }

Comment: this is from the mainPage.xaml.cs file

Comment: I took a bit from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890836/how-to-pass-an-object-from-a-frame-to-another-frame-in-a-windows-8-style-app) @Greg. Use the OnNavigatedTo handler.

Comment: i used the code in ur answer and nothing happened. I would like to clear things up quickly: All I want is for the text that the user types in textbox1 (which is in MainPage) to be set to the text of userTab (which is in welcomePage. Sorry if I confused you, as I changed the names of some things recently.

Comment: Post your updated code, and don't forget to include your main page next_Click function @Greg

Comment: i will post a screenshot of mainPage and of welcomePage

Comment: @Greg So what's it doing now? Add some breakpoints in, see if it's hitting on the onPageNavigated and it's setting this.username in.

Comment: also i dont want test.text to be the username, i want textbox1 to be, sorry if i made this confusing

Answer (score 0):

You need to either create an instance of `MainPage` (and ensure that the `textbox1` member is not private) or you need to make the `textbox1` member static. Those are the only two ways to access `textbox1.Text` directly from another class.

Realistically in your case though you should make an instance of `MainPage` in your `welcomePage` class because the other option might cause thread safety issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use public static field

```cs
public static string UserName { get; set; }

public void test_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string user = MainPage.textbox1.Text;
    welcomePage.UserName = test.Text;
    box.Text = "User: " + welcomePage.UserName;
 }
```

Comment: I'm weary about this, because there may be a time where there can be multiple MainPage forms running, and this will cause thread safety issue.